# Accessing magento's checkout/cart using REST API

Tags: api, rest, checkout, magento-1.7

I'm trying to integrate a cart-synchronisation-solution for my rest-clients.
The goal should be that I can have the same cart wherever I access my store from.

So I'll have to first of all deliver the existing items out to the client using the authenticated api-user.

But I get stuck at the very beginning:

```
protected function _retrieveCollection()
{
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    $cart->setCustomerId($this->getApiUser()->getUserId());
    $cart->setStoreId(4);
    $cart->load();

    return $cart->getAllItems();
}
```

returns an empty array even though I have products in my cart.

Anyone any hints? Have that feeling I'm totally on the wrong side...

Comment: Is it possible to check out using REST? Because I have asked one question regarding REST on SO and I got answer that we can't access check out and other thing using REST!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454251/android-app-for-magento-store-using-rest-or-soap

Comment: @vsvankhede he is developing rest api's not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Getting the quote by Customer which is the other way around worked pretty well:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(4);
$cart = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($this->getApiUser()->getUserId());
$items = array();
foreach ($cart->getAllVisibleItems() as $key => $item) {
    $items[] = array(
        'name'                  => $item->getName(),
        'entity_id'             => $item->getProductId(),
        'description'           => $item->getDescription(),
        'final_price_with_tax'  => $item->getBasePriceInclTax(),
        'qty'                   => $item->getQty()
    );

}
```

Comment: axel your answer is right and working like charm but when I try to return $items in the end of function it is showing only 'qty' of each item but in case of echo it show all. I want json response of this but got stuck here due to return.